# Going from a binary RPM to an OBS signed rpm?

Tags: rpm, fpm, open-build-service

I have a RPM that I'm currently building with FPM,

```
fpm --verbose \
  -s dir \
  -t rpm \
  --directories /opt/myprod
  --name myprod
  --rpm-summary "My Prod"
  --version $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
  --rpm-sign
  --rpm-digest sha512 ./myprod=/opt/
```

This essentially creates an rpm **from a directory** that does **exactly** what I want. It works perfectly.

But, my company has their own signing key that can not be shared on an [Open Build Service (OBS)](https://openbuildservice.org/) server. I don't *need* to use FPM at all if OBS can do everything. What I do need is some *understanding* of how I go from the directory `./myprod` to an RPM which installs it under `/opt/myprod`.

I'm new to RPM packaging. I assume I could take this directory and `.tar.gz` it and submit it to to OBS to be packaged and signed. I assume I need to somehow specify this with a spec file?

What is the most simple way to accomplish this. Ideally, I wouldn't have to manually generate a spec file. Is any of this provided by OBS?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK on OBS you cannot your own GPG key. It will generate a new one for your project.

If you want to use your own GPG key you have to sign it yourself: https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#Signing-Packages